# Default look of editable table cells in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I would like to have first column in my table editable. That works fine. However table looks normal and only when I click on the editable cell, it looks like input box. I would like to have this look of inputbox as default on every editable column in my table, so user knows right away which cell he is able to modify and which one he cannot. I figured I will have to modify caspian.css, but I couldn't find anything there. Is there easier, programmatic way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cellFactory of your column, inside it you can specify what you want by default on your cell by setting is graphics 
 [explanation](http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/)
and [here](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/01/tableview-cell-modifiy-in-javafx/)

Comment: I did it but it doesnt work correctly. In my cellfactory where I handle all editing operations I added setgraphics where I specify CSS code for editbox from caspian.css file. Its almost good, but now when I want to edit something, I get small box inside of a big one. It looks quite ugly